# Spring Integration Flow with @Restcontoller Timing issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

A simple @RestController is connected with a @MessagingGateway to an IntegrationFlow.
After a load test we saw within the tracing that we lose "a lot of time" before even starting the processing within the flow:
[Tracing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9X92.png)
In this example we can see that over 90ms spend befor sending the message to the flow.
Did anyone have some idea what leads to this behavior?
As far as I understood the documentation, everything is handled in the sender thread and therefore no special worker threads are created.
We use the Restcontroller since we need to create the documentation with springdoc-openapi-ui

ExampleCode:

RestController

```
@RestController
public class DescriptionEndpoint {

   HttpMessageGateway httpMessageGateway;
   public Result findData(@Valid dataRequest dataRequest) {
      final Map<String, Object> headerParams = new HashMap<>();
      return httpMessageGateway.basicDataDescriptionFlow(dataRequest, headerParams);
   }
}
```

Gateway

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface HttpMessageGateway {

   @Gateway(requestChannel = "startDataFlow.input")
   Result basicDataDescriptionFlow(@Payload dataRequest prDataRequest, @Headers Map<String, Object> map);

}
```

IntegrationFlow

```
public class ExampleFlow {
   
   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow startDataFlow() {
      return new FlowExtension()
          .handle(someHandler1)
          .handle(someHandler2)
          .handle(someHandler3)
          .get();
   }
}
```

Comment: Does it happen all the time or only for the first request? Would be great if you share with us a simple project to let us to reproduce and play with?

Comment: It happens all the time. 
I added some more traces and found the issue being within in the security configuration. 
Furthermore its some JWT validation that has been implemented inperformant. 
Unfortunatelly, i thought, the span is only representing the time after the start of findData(..). But it seems, the tracing starts already in the proxy methods and security chain.

Comment: Cool! Glad you have it figured out. Feel free to add it as an answer to your own question. Also feel free to raise a JWT token validation concern against Spring Security project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues

Answer (score 0):

After adding some more traces I realized, that this timing issue is caused by my spring security configuration.
Unfortunatelly, i thought, the span is only representing the time after the start of findData(..). But it seems, the tracing starts already in the proxy methods and security chain.

After improving some implementation on our JWTToken filter, the spend times for these endpoints are OK.